# How to push a file to android device by using gitbash

Tags: android, shell, adb, git-bash

I need to push a file to `system/bin` of my android device via Gitbash but it fails because it refers to system of my git.

```
adb push file1 /system/bin
```

```
>failed to copy 'file1' to 'C:/Program Files/Git/system/bin': No such file or directory*
```

I tried also with command prompt, getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pushing you need your device to be rooted and remounted as this:

- `adb root`
- `adb remount`

And then proceed like this (watch out for the additional slash you have)

- `adb push file1 system/bin/`

Comment: If you use a OS based in Linux you will can push a library or apk in device with the slash. The problem seems to be that in Windows, the slash represents the root of the disk.
As we can see -> "C:/Program Files/Git/system/bin"

Comment: Thanks Victor, that makes perfect sense!